# js object wrong scope resulting in empty objects?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code, but unfortunately all the objects in items array are empty. I think it is a scoping issue, but wasn't able to figure it out by myself:

```
var items = [];
var itemCount = results.data.length;
$.each(results.data, function(index) {
      var item = results.data[index];
      item.index = index;

      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
        item.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        item.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        items.push(item);
        console.log(items[0]); // --> prints object with all properties

        if (items.length === itemCount) {
          console.log(items); // --> prints 3 empty objects
        }
      });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are pushing the item in `stops` instead of `items`.

Comment: Sry that was just an editing issue. I corrected it.

Comment: Do you see your objects still fully populated when you log them individually using at `console.log(item[0])`?

Comment: @ZaidAjaj Kind of. The properties are all listed as > Object {streetNumber: ...} as you can see in the console output image. I would normally expect that the properties appear as a list when I open the Object dropdown

Comment: @Chris, try `alert`ing a property of each object instead of logging them to console, maybe there is something wrong with how Chrome's console outputs the object array....try this: `items.map(function (item) { return item.streetNumber; }).forEach(alert);`

Answer (score 0):

See if it work for you:

```
var item = {};
$.each(results.data, function(index, value) {
    item[index] = value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        item.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        item.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var stops = [];
        stops.push(item);
        console.log(stops[0]); // --> prints object with all properties

        if(stops.length === stopCount){
             console.log(stops); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get a valid object inside stops when I initialize it within the geocode callback as you do it in the code above. But this resets stops at every iteration and I end up with only one object in the array